# Get sub-account's Futures account balance using KuCoin API and Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, http-status-code-404, kucoin

I am trying to get a value (USDT) from KuCoin sub-account's Futures account but having an issue. Here is the script:

```
function getKuCoinBalance(apiKey, secretKey, passphrase, asset) {
    var endpoint = "/api/v1/accounts";
    var baseUrl = "https://api.kucoin.com";
    var timestamp = Date.now().toString();
    var method = "GET";

    var strForSign = timestamp + method + endpoint;
    var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_256, strForSign, secretKey);
    var encodedSignature = Utilities.base64Encode(signature);

    var passphraseHash = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_256, passphrase, secretKey);
    var encodedPassphrase = Utilities.base64Encode(passphraseHash);
 
    var options = {
        'method' : method,
        'headers' : {
            'KC-API-SIGN' : encodedSignature,
            'KC-API-TIMESTAMP' : timestamp,
            'KC-API-KEY' : apiKey,
            'KC-API-PASSPHRASE' : encodedPassphrase,
            'KC-API-KEY-VERSION' : '2'
        }
    };

    var url = baseUrl + endpoint;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    Logger.log(response)
    var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    var data = dataAll.data;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].currency == asset) {
            return data[i].balance;
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to get data of different types of accounts (`trade, isolated, main`), you can find the API information [**Here**](https://docs.kucoin.com/#list-accounts), but I am looking to get sub-account's Futures account details, as shown in the `following image`:

[image: USDT Value]

I believe I am making a mistake in using the correct URL, I reckon the correct url can be `/api/v1/account-overview?currency=USDT` but it throws the following error:

> Exception: Request failed for https://api.kucoin.com returned code
> 404. Truncated server response: {"code":"404","msg":"Not Found","retry":false,"success":false} (use muteHttpExceptions option
> to examine full response)

Can you please guide me in the right direction? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On looking the [API Information](https://docs.kucoin.com/#list-accounts) that you provided in your question, I found this [endpoint](https://docs.kucoin.com/#get-account-balance-of-a-sub-account) that can be used to get the balance of any sub-account. So here is the workflow:

1. First, get the user id of your sub-account by using this request:
   `/api/v1/sub-accounts`
2. Then use this user id in your code. So the modified script would be:

**Script Code:**

```
 function getKuCoinSubAccountFuturesBalance(apiKey, secretKey, passphrase, currency) {
  var endpoint = "/api/v1/account-overview";
  var baseUrl = "https://api-futures.kucoin.com";
  var timestamp = Date.now().toString();
  var method = "GET";

  var strForSign = timestamp + method + endpoint +"?currency="+currency;
  var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_256, strForSign, secretKey);
  var encodedSignature = Utilities.base64Encode(signature);

  var passphraseHash = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_256, passphrase, secretKey);
  var encodedPassphrase = Utilities.base64Encode(passphraseHash);

  var options = {
    method: method,
    headers: {
      'KC-API-SIGN': encodedSignature,
      'KC-API-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
      'KC-API-KEY': apiKey,
      'KC-API-PASSPHRASE': encodedPassphrase,
      'KC-API-KEY-VERSION': '2'
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };

  var url = baseUrl + endpoint +"?currency="+currency;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  return dataAll.data.accountEquity;
}
```

**Note: Use Sub Account credentials (API and Secret key)**

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I followed your instructions, it gave the following output:
`{"subUserId":"###","subName":"###","mainAccounts":[],"tradeAccounts":[],"marginAccounts":[],"tradeHFAccounts":[]}}` it did not provide any info about Futures assets of this subaccount.

Comment: I have modified the script, let me know if it solves your issue.